# groovy.lang.Script - получить класс по имени

Tags: java, groovy

Допустим, я загрузил и исполнил (run) скрипт на языке Groovy в Java. Теперь у меня есть экземпляр объекта класса groovy.lang.Script. Я могу вызывать из него функции с помощью invokeMethod. А что делать если в скрипте был объявлен класс и я знаю его имя, а мне нужно создать экземпляр такого класса в Java?

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = shell.parse(new File("/path/to/script.groovy"));
script.run();
script.invokeMethod("foo", new Object[] { "bar" });
```

Код выше загружает скрипт из файла, исполняет его, а затем дёргает объявленную в нём функцию foo с параметром bar. А что делать если я хочу дёргать не только функции, но и классы?

**UPD:**

Я смог сделать код, который бы загружал класс из скрипта:

```
private static Class loadClassFromScript(Script script, String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final Package package_ = script.getClass().getPackage();
    final String classNamePrefix = (package_ != null) ? package_.getName() + "." : "";
    return Class.forName(classNamePrefix + className, true, script.getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

Он отлично работает кроме случая, когда скрипт не содержит исполняемых конструкций, а только лишь декларацию класса. Что делать в этом случае?